# Membership ASP.NET GetPassword

Tags: asp.net-membership

I want to do GetPassword() on MembershipUser but the custom membership provider in the application is throwing NotImplemented exception, let me know some workaround to get any users password ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a custom membership provider, that means you have created a class that inherits `MembershipProvider`. When you inherit this class, visual studio will typically go ahead and auto generate the abstract methods that you inherit from MembershipProvider. One of those methods is GetPassword(), and it's up to you to program the logic for it. By default, it throws that exception reminding you that you haven't written the logic for it yet.

[image]

If you didn't want to do a custom membership provider, you can use a `SqlMembershipProvider` instead and let visual studio create the necessary tables and stored procedures to handle everything. A custom membership provider is used when you want full control over the programming logic.